# Is it anyhow possible to use QoS with DSCP in Windows10 Home?

Tags: windows-10, networking

I know `gpedit.msc` is not available in Windows10 Home versions in general.

However I have came across to an article which let me install this policy editor (and I believe all required components too):

https://www.itechtics.com/enable-gpedit-windows-10-home/

In spite on all my efforts I can't change the DSCP fields of the packets at all.

In the editor it seems I have changed it, but it's not taking the effect in real.

I know Home edition is not really designed for these kind of QoS capabilities, but still, someone might know a quickfix for this without completely reinstalling the whole OS?

I would like to change the DSCP for a particular application (.exe).

Each and every packet generated from that specific application shall contain my desired DSCPs.

I am opened to any recommendations beside reinstalling Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: Generally, QoS is best done at the router level - is this not possible/why are you choosing to do this at the OS level?

Comment: Because I want to separate an *application* from others. The "to-be-separated" application is using many dst addresses, many ports, and both TCP and UDP, so it's impossible to do this in router. (or nearly impossible).